# How can I add sign up back into Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Im working on an project after taking a break on it for a few months. At the time I didn't want to allow user to Sign up and instead add new users from the console. Now Ive changed my mind and want to allow a sign up form. The only problem is I cant remember how I disabled it in the first place.

How can I add user sign ups back in to my rails app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you disabled "sign up," and the bit where you complained about "sign in" is an error.

Sign up (AKA registration) is enabled or disabled in the model against which you've installed Devise (typically your `User` model). Open up that model file and you'l see something like the following:

```
devise :authenticatable, :database_authenticatable,
        :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable,
        :trackable, request_keys: [:subdomain]
```

The line in your file will be missing the `:registerable` symbol. Just add that symbol back to enable registration.

Comment: That worked, but now id like the edit the html and theres no file to do. tried `rails generate devise:views` nothing happened. where is the html for this form even coming from?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please click the checkmark to the left of the answer to let people know the information worked for you. As for your views, you should post another question, seeing as you actually are asking another question. Generating Devise views probably worked, but you just didn't know where to look. Try looking for `app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb`.